# How to specify that a combobox use a specific ComboBoxItem Template

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a wpf ComboboxItem template that works fine.
I ONLY want it applied to specific comboboxes by way of a specific Combobox style. I don't know where in the combobox style that I should point it to the combobox item style. Any suggestions

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       ...
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I'm thinking it should be specified near here.
                              Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" 
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                              ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="s" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
   ...
</Style>

<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxWithoutItemStyle"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxWithItemStyle" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource s}"/>
```

**Update based on comment**: or, as part of a style:

```
<Style x:Key="s2" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource s}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: How do I incorporate your rersponse as part of STYLE?
        <Style x:Key="ComboBox_B" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" >